# JavaScript code does not seem to work as intended for the xml elements

Tags: javascript, css, xml, dom

I am basically for now just trying to show "Blue OTHER" column only when the row element "Blue" appears on the screen (while it should be hidden when not). Currently when "Blue" row appears as the card on screen the "Blue OTHER" column remains hidden.

I can't seem to get something working. The question resides within the https://forstasurveys.zendesk.com/hc/en-us platform if that is of any consideration.

here is my current code:

```
<radio 
  label="Q1"
  cardsort:displayCounter="0"
  shuffle="rows"
  uses="cardsort.6">
  <title>Select a feeling associated with each colour</title>
  <comment>Place each card into a bucket.</comment>
  <style name="question.after"><![CDATA[
<style name="question.after">
  #question_Q1 > div.sq-cardsort.sq-cardsort-Q1.sq-cardsort-mobile > div.sq-cardsort-body > div.sq-cardsort-buckets-view > ul > li.sq-cardsort-bucket.sq-cardsort-bucket-c5.ui-droppable {
    display: none !important;
  }
</style>

<script>
  const blueRow = document.querySelector('.blueRow');
  const blueOther = document.querySelector('#question_Q1B > div.sq-cardsort.sq-cardsort-Q1B.sq-cardsort-mobile > div.sq-cardsort-body > div.sq-cardsort-buckets-view > ul > li.sq-cardsort-bucket.sq-cardsort-bucket-c5.ui-droppable');

  blueRow.addEventListener('click', () => {
    blueOther.style.display = 'table-cell';
  });
</script>
]]></style>
  <row label="r1"><span class="blueRow">Blue</span></row>
  <row label="r2"><span class="redRow">Red</span></row>
  <row label="r3">Green</row>
  <row label="r4">Yellow</row>
  <row label="r5">Pink</row>
  <row label="r6">Purple</row>
  <row label="r7">Orange</row>
  <row label="r8">Black</row>
  <row label="r9">White</row>
  <row label="r10">Gray</row>
  <col label="c1">Happiness</col>
  <col label="c2">Excitement</col>
  <col label="c3">Power</col>
  <col label="c4">Sadness</col>
  <col label="c5" open="1" openSize="25" randomize="0"><span class="blueCol">Blue OTHER</span></col>
  <col label="c6" open="1" openSize="25" randomize="0"><span class="redCol">Red OTHER</span></col>
  <col label="c7" open="1" openSize="25" randomize="0">Green OTHER</col>
  <col label="c8" open="1" openSize="25" randomize="0">Yellow OTHER</col>
  <col label="c9" open="1" openSize="25" randomize="0">Pink OTHER</col>
  <col label="c10" open="1" openSize="25" randomize="0">Purple OTHER</col>
  <col label="c11" open="1" openSize="25" randomize="0">Orange OTHER</col>
  <col label="c12" open="1" openSize="25" randomize="0">Black OTHER</col>
  <col label="c13" open="1" openSize="25" randomize="0">White OTHER</col>
  <col label="c14" open="1" openSize="25" randomize="0">Gray OTHER</col>
</radio>
```

Any help or suggestions at all is much appreciated.

Comment: You seem to be changing blueother when blue is clicked, not when it comes into the viewport.